# How to split array dynamically based on single value in JavaScript Node.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, pug

I need to split array dynamically based on single value in JavaScript.

I've got an array:

```
var dataStuff = [
    { Name: 'Apple', Tag: 'Fruit', Price: '2,5'},
    { Name: 'Bike', Tag: 'Sport', Price: '150'},
    { Name: 'Kiwi', Tag: 'Fruit', Price: '1,5'},
    { Name: 'Knife', Tag: 'Kitchen', Price: '8'},
    { Name: 'Fork', Tag: 'Kitchen', Price: '7'}
];
```

And i expect arrays split by Tag,
eg.

```
var Fruit = [
    { Name: 'Apple', Tag: 'Fruit', Price: '2,5'},
    { Name: 'Kiwi', Tag: 'Fruit', Price: '1,5'}
];

var Sport = [
    { Name: 'Bike', Tag: 'Sport', Price: '150'}
];

var Kitchen = [
    { Name: 'Knife', Tag: 'Kitchen', Price: '8'},
    { Name: 'Fork', Tag: 'Kitchen', Price: '7'}
];
```

If in dataStuff array will be more **Tags** then in result will be more arrays.
Anyway i don't have idea how should I do this. I'm using node.js + Jade (for view), and i think the best idea will be do this at view because i have to put each array in **table**. Maybe something like this:

```
// Basic table
tbody
     - each item in dataStuff
         tr
            td= item.Name
            td= item.Tag
            td= item.Price

// Other tables
- each item in dataStuff
    item.Tag.push(item);
    // adding items to array based on Tag
    // probably it won't work 
    // but still how should i draw table?
```

I would be grateful for any help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use an object with the grouped items. It works for any tags and allows a list of all tags with `Object.keys(grouped)`, if required.

```js
var dataStuff = [{ Name: 'Apple', Tag: 'Fruit', Price: '2,5' }, { Name: 'Bike', Tag: 'Sport', Price: '150' }, { Name: 'Kiwi', Tag: 'Fruit', Price: '1,5' }, { Name: 'Knife', Tag: 'Kitchen', Price: '8' }, { Name: 'Fork', Tag: 'Kitchen', Price: '7' }],
    grouped = Object.create(null);

dataStuff.forEach(function (a) {
    grouped[a.Tag] = grouped[a.Tag] || [];
    grouped[a.Tag].push(a);
});

document.write(Object.keys(grouped));
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(grouped, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: how does it help to have a completely empty object? `Object.create(null)`

Comment: because you could have a tag `toString`, that would not work.

Comment: What if my dataStuff is from database? How can i use `grouped = Object.create(null);` then? `var groupedstuff = dataStuff, grouped = Object.create(null);` - probably it won't work?

Comment: @Nina Scholz do you mean `grouped[a.tag]toString()` would not work? or "[object Object]" shouldn't appear?

Comment: @DiPix, i do not understand your question.

Comment: @AmreshVenugopal, `grouped['toString'].push(...)` would not work, because `grouped.toString` is a function.

Comment: In your solution I make this object dataStuff. But i received this object from another function. `function (dataStuff) {
            [...// here i should group somehow] }`

Comment: @NinaScholz I never thought that way before!

Comment: @DiPix, if `dataStuff` is an array, or if it is like an array with iterations, the it should work.

Comment: That's an elegant solution, @NinaScholz

Answer (score -1):

If your tag names are known in advance and limited

then simply

```
var Fruit = dataStuff.filter(function(val){
  return val.Tag == "Fruit";
});
var Sport = dataStuff.filter(function(val){
  return val.Tag == "Sport";
});
var Kitchen = dataStuff.filter(function(val){
  return val.Tag == "Kitchen";
});
```

Or you can create a JSON object keeping the Tag Names like

```
var tags = {
  "Fruit" : [],
  "Sport" : [],
  "Kitchen" : [],
};
for(var tag in tags)
{
   tags[tag] = dataStuff.filter(function(val){
      return val.Tag == tag;
    });  
}
```

Now `tags.Fruit` will give you the `Fruit` array.

Comment: No, they are not known. That's why, it must be dynamic.

Comment: @DiPix I have given an option for that as well.

Comment: Your solution is trivial and unhelpful - op uses the word 'dynamic'