# How to display value of grouped objects at jade template in javascript node.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, pug, pugjs

Based on this [How to split array dynamically based on single value in JavaScript Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36833978/how-to-split-array-dynamically-based-on-single-value-in-javascript-node-js)
i created object with Arrays, and i can display name of each array by this:

```
- each item in Object.keys(groupedData)
         li= item
```

result is:

```
* Fruit
* Sport
* Kitchen
```

However how can I display value of each array in diffrent tables?
eg. [image: example of table]

I don't know how to take any value from array?

I thought about this `li= item.array[0].tag` but it doesn't work.

---

@EDIT

If I use:

```
 - each val, key in groupedData
         li #{JSON.stringify(val)}
```

I can display values, result at view:

```
[{"name":"Apple","tag":"Fruit","price": 2},
{"name":"Kiwi","tag":"Fruit","price": 1}]
```

But how can i put this to table?

Comment: you are iterating on `Object.keys(object);` you need to iterate on the `groupedData` object itself.

Comment: Right, check my edit now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a small example that you can see working [in this codepen](http://codepen.io/souldreamer/pen/PNdqge)

```
- var groupedData = {'X': [{'a': 'x0', 'b': 'x1'},{'a': 'xx0', 'b': 'xx1'}], 'Y': [{'a': 'y0', 'b': 'y1'},{'a': 'yy0', 'b': 'yy1'}], 'Z': [{'a': 'z0', 'b': 'z1'},{'a': 'zz0', 'b': 'zz1'}]}
- each grp in Object.keys(groupedData)
  h1= grp
  table
    thead
      - each val, index in groupedData[grp][0]
        th= index
    - each subgrp in groupedData[grp]
      tr
        - each val in subgrp
          td= val
```